# Christoffel symbols

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, tensors

In a book, which I am reading, the next equality appears:
$$\Gamma_{ij}^k=\vec{E^k}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec{E_i}}{\partial u^j}\qquad (1)$$
where 
$$\vec{E_i}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u^i}\qquad and\qquad \vec{E^k}=\nabla u^{k}$$
Then we use spherical coordinates, and we have:
$$\vec{E_\rho}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \rho}=\sin\theta\cos\varphi\boldsymbol{\hat{{\imath}}}+\sin\theta\cos\varphi\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}+\cos\theta\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}=\hat{e_\rho}$$
and we know the transformation for spherical coordinates are $\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{z}\right)$
$$\vec{E^\theta}=\nabla \theta=\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2+y^2}{z^2}}\cdot\frac{x}{z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2+y^2}{z^2}}\cdot\frac{y}{z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2+y^2}{z^2}}\cdot\frac{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z^2}\right)$$
we know $x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho^2$; $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\rho\sin\theta$; 
 $x=\rho\sin\theta\cos\varphi$ ; $y=\rho\sin\theta\sin\varphi$ ; $z=\rho\cos\theta$
$$\nabla\theta=\frac{z}{\rho^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left(x,y,-\frac{x^2+y^2}{z}\right)=\frac{1}{\rho}(\cos\theta\cos\varphi,\cos\theta\sin\varphi,-\sin\theta)=\frac{\hat{e_\theta}}{\rho}$$
therefore, we come back to equation (1)
$$\Gamma_{\rho\theta}^{\theta}=\vec{E^\theta}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec{E_\rho}}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\hat{e_\theta}}{\rho}\cdot\frac{\partial e_\rho}{\partial \theta}=\frac{1}{\rho}\hat{e_\theta}\cdot\hat{e_\theta}=\frac{1}{\rho}$$
The question is: is this procedure good, are the followed steps good?

God bless you.